Why would a program abend with SQL -927?
We are upgrading our COBOL version from <4.2 to 4.2. I am facing an issue where one job fails because of SQL -927.
The job involves an IMS module and at the end, it calls a DB2 Module.
The last program of the entire call chain is a DB2 program.
ERROR IN OPENING PPOS-CURSOR                                                    
IN PARA 1000-INITIALIZE-PROCESS                                                 
SQLCODE  = 000000927-                                                           
SQLERRML = 00000+                                                               
SQLERRMC =                                                                      
SQLERRP  = DSNELI                                                               
CEE3250C The system or user abend U 759 R=NULL     was issued.                  
         From compile unit PPOS at entry point PPOS at compile unit offs
          at address 0034E8F6.                                                  

I tried multiple recompilations but it was not corrected.

SQL code -927: THE LANGUAGE INTERFACE (LI) WAS CALLED WHEN THE CONNECTING ENVIRONMENT WAS NOT ESTABLISHED. THE PROGRAM SHOULD BE INVOKED UNDER THE DSN COMMAND

The COBOL program is not initialized or not set up correctly in the JCL.

Since this involves IMS you might have to link DFSLI000 instesad of DSNELI. But it's simpler to just link DSNULI which should work for all environments.

You need to invoke the program via the DSN command. The JCL that invoked the older version should work just fine.

The SQLCODE -927 indicates that the application is attempting to execute a DB2 SQL statement, but the required DB2 environment is not properly initialized. Ensure that the IMS and DB2 subsystems are correctly configured to work together, and verify that the application is properly linked with the DB2 attachment module (DSNELI). Additionally, check the JCL to confirm that the appropriate DB2 region or plan is specified and active before the program executes the DB2 module.
